# Can't Show Turkish Characters When Getting Column Names

Tags: php, mysql, encoding, character

I'm trying to get column names with Turkish characters. Here is the code.

```
$cekelim=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM kategori");
$sayisi=mysql_num_fields($cekelim);
for($i=0;$i<$sayisi;$i++){
$listeleyelim=mysql_field_name($cekelim,$i);
echo $listeleyelim."<br>";
}
```

And I used these codes in the beginning of php file

```
mb_internal_encoding('UTF-8');
mysql_query('SET NAMES UTF8');
mysql_query("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
mysql_query("SET COLLATION_CONNECTION = 'utf8_turkish_ci'");
```

And also I used

```
<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/HTML; charset=utf-8' />
```

between head tags in html.

**Edit1:**

Adding

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9');
```

fixes ü and ö but doesn't work for only-in-Turkish characters.

**Edit2:**

I replaced all Turkish characters with numerical codes such as &#231 and I'm replacing all Turkish characters with numerical codes when inputting a new column. This is not the exact way I was looking for but this alternate way works fine.

Comment: What are columns collation? Set utf8_general_ci

Comment: didn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Can you tell us what the problem is? You say what you want but you don't explain the prolem you encounter. I don't see any problem in your code.

Comment: The problem is I get ü,ö's replaced with � and İ,ı,ç,ş,ğ's replaced with ?. I think the title of question is clear enough to be understood. It's a typical character problem most of the coders face.

Comment: This may be a problem with the coding (i.e. charset) of the HTML page as other people have pointed. If you create a PHP connection in UTF-8 then not only serve your file as UTF-8 but make sure the file itself is coded as such.

Comment: BTW your question is not clear at all. You talk about SQL and PHP where this is really an encoding / HTML problem. You should give a link to the HTML file.

Comment: But in source code the characters are not Turkish characters.

Comment: It's not about the source code, it's about the output in the browser, right?

Comment: I meant HTML codes produced by Apache by saying source code. There are �'s and ?'s when I press ctrl+U.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34015/discussion-between-sebastien-and-zencimusa)

Answer (score 0):

Use `header` to modify the HTTP header:

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
```

Or:

```
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-9');
```

Comment: After using the second one, I can see ü,ö but not ı,ğ.
Then I realized it spoiled every only-in-Turkish characters.

Comment: `<meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/HTML; charset=iso-8859-9' />`